# Trailing zeros in byte array from RawBsonDocument.getByteBuffer().array() in org.Bson

Tags: java, mongodb, byte, bson, org.json

I am trying to encode an org.Json JSONObject into a BSON format byte[].
I have noticed, however, that the resulting byte[] has trailing zeros. While these zeros do not pose a problem when deserializing the byte[] to JSON again, they do however take up a lot of space.
My code is the following:

```
#deserializing incoming message
RawBsonDocument bson = new RawBsonDocument((byte[])incomingBson);
json = new JSONObject(bson.toJson());

#serializing response to **bson format**
RawBsonDocument bsonDoc = RawBsonDocument.parse(json.toString());
responseBson = bsonDoc.getByteBuffer().array();
```

Simply trimming the byte[] from all trailing zeroes is not an option, since the byte[] can very well have valid zeros at the end, that where not added by the serialization.

**Edit 1**

I solved the issue with the following code:

```
RawBsonDocument bsonDoc = RawBsonDocument.parse(json.toString());
responseBson = Arrays.copyOfRange(bsonDoc.getByteBuffer().array(), 0, bsonDoc.getByteBuffer().limit());
```

I feel as tough the must be a more elegant answer

Comment: You need to take account of the `limit()` of the `ByteBuffer`, rather than assuming it is full.

Comment: Good Point!
I updated my answer with a possible solution including the `limit()` function.
Maybe you can repost you comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You should really use the `get()` methods rather than sidestepping the whole design of the class like this.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, and I agree, that would be the ideal case. However, in my scenario, I have to work with a JSON file of unknown and potentially varying structure. Also, in my example,  it may be a JSONObject. But the the input may just aswell be a loaded JSON file. So parsing the entire object from a string representation seemed to be the best way to deal with that, without having to worry about the varying structure of the JSON.

Comment: Or would iterating over every token in the JSON individually yield a better result?
I also know, that doing it in this way, I may end up with a byte[] that's larger than simply sending the plain JSON. That is okay however, since it is exactly what I wanted to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this problem in a similar class and solved it by making a truncated copy of the internal buffer.

Since `getByteBuffer` returns the internal buffer which the document object holds, the ending unused spaces are filled with zeros, which caused the problem.

Here is my solution:

```
return Arrays.copyOf(writeBuffer.getInternalBuffer(), writeBuffer.getSize());
```

where `writeBuffer` is a `BasicOutputBuffer` instance which implements org.bson's `OutputBuffer` interface. So this should also work in your situation.